# Set theory exercise involving setminus: $A\subseteq B$ iff $A\setminus B^c = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A\subseteq B$ iff $A\setminus B^c = A$

Attempted proof - Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in (A\setminus B^c)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ since $A\subseteq B$. So $x\in A\cap A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$. Thus, we have $A\setminus B^c = A$.

Conversely, if $A\setminus B^c = A$ we can write $$A = (A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)$$ so if $x\in A$ then $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in (A\setminus B)$ or both....

Not really sure where I am going with this any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c$ so

$$A\setminus B^c=A\iff A\cap B=A\iff A\subset B$$
Notice that we prove the last equivalence easily by double inclusion.

Comment: Are you saying that $A\setminus B^c = A\cap B$?

Comment: Yes I said it.${}$

Comment: Ok, then if I already proved that: $A\subseteq B$ iff $A\cap B = A$ then I am done?

Comment: If so I have already proved $\Rightarrow$ but I am not sure how to prove the converse there is a question posted on this that I made an hour ago and no one has shown the converse if you want to submit an proof for that part

Comment: Assume that $A\cap B=A$ and let $x\in A=A\cap B$ so $x\in B$. Hence $A\subset B$.

Comment: Really that's all you have to say?

Comment: Yes that's all:-)